# Vue - Use v-model with v-for affecting value of all rows

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
<template>
  <div class="cont" v-for="index in 10" :key="index">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" v-model="rows[index-1].numInput" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" v-model="rows[index-1].num2Input" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        rows: Array(10).fill({
          numInput: '',
          num2Input: '',
        }),
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I'm trying to v-for 10 rows of input and bind with the array `rows` , but when I input at 1 input, then the other 9 inputs value is filled with the value. How do I prevent the input of each array index is not affected with each other ?

The array index is already different in every loop, but it still interfering each other.

[DEMO HERE](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements in your array are references to the same object:

```js
const arr = Array(2).fill({numInput: '', num2Input: ''})
console.log('Same object:', arr[0] === arr[1])
```

Have a look at the [documentation of `fill()` on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

> all elements in the array will be this exact value: if value is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

To pass in individual objects, you can use `Array.from()`:

```
Array.from({length: 10}, () => ({numInput: '', num2Input: ''}))
```